# Downsides to supporting generic query conditions in REST APIs?

Tags: web-services, rest, web-applications, api-design, restful-architecture

I'd like to know what the trade-offs are of having one's REST API support a wide variety of query constraints. I'm thinking along the lines of what an API [like that of Parse](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#queries-constraints) does.

Parse's take on REST allows one to almost entirely build a DB statement on the client, and I imagine that on the server they have an engine that translates the where: {} JSON key into a proper Mongo query that includes all of the defined conditions. For example, here's something one could do:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xxx" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: xxx" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"hometown":{"$select":{"query":{"className":"Team","where":{"winPct":{"$gt":0.5}}},"key":"city"}}}' \
  --data-urlencode 'limit=200' \
  --data-urlencode 'skip=400' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User
```

As you can see from the data section, one could generate some rather complex and interesting queries on the client by using this very flexible system. Now let's assume you're not Parse, you're using SQL, and your (private!) API's requirement is not to support every imaginable type of query a client could make, but you could still benefit of being able to define a few constraints here and there to avoid sending data to the client that it won't use, simply because it can't define a query with sufficient precision.

Is the DB-statement-generation engine approach simply an overkill in the above case?
If so, what's a simpler way of dealing with having different resources share a few constraints (like limit, skip, ordering), but not all of them? Some might be specific to that resource. Any great resources that talk about the various design decisions here?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a RESTful architecture, you need to use HATEOAS, which means that the queries need to be generated based on the representations sent in previous responses. A "DB-statement-generation engine" **is therefore unnecessary**, as all options that can be set will be provided as a template by the server (e.g. a HTML form, but probably something more complex in your case, perhaps XForms in a custom content type). The constraints will be defined by the form input markup. Choose a markup language adequate enough to describe all of your constraints to the client.

Comment: At this point I'm not trying to achieve full compliance with "true REST". The API is REST-like at best because of its use of HTTP verbs and URIs, it doesn't try to be discoverable and to serve content in whatever media format is asked of it.